# Autostart App on Smartwatch 2 after wakeup - Disable sony watchface on wakeup

Tags: android, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am working on APP for smartwatch 2. But i need my app to keep running even when the watch wake up or watch is turned on . 
Right now when watch wakes up, it goes back to sony watchface. I need my app to keep running.

Please help .  you can check user reviews on play store .

Check my app on google play store .. Name is : PixelS Watch for Smartwatch 2

Comment: Your comment down at Marlin's answer makes clear what you want. You want to program a custom watch face. Maybe you should mention that in your question because the question is … not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain more specifically what you are trying to accomplish?  Currently the watchface will only show when the watch goes into low power mode (LPM).  If your extension is running and the watch goes into LPM then it shows the watch face, but when it wakes up your extension should receive a resume event and can continue to run.

If the watch is turned off while your extension is running there isn't a way to resume it if the watch is turned back on.  The user has to manually relaunch the extension.

Comment: Thanx Marlin for helping me out.  Actually what i am trying to accomplish is: 
my app "Pixels watch For Smartwatch 2" is a Custom Watchface app. Whenever i press power button on my smartwatch 2 or when watch goes to Low Power Mode, it shows sony's default watchface. I need to override that watchface and make my own custom watchface to show whenever watch goes dim(low power mode) or when we press power button.                                                              There is an app named"Custom Watch for Smartwatch" on playstore which has implemented this.. Please help